# How to access class properties from static methods in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have such code

```coffee
class Class
  property: 5

  @run: ->
    console.log @property

Class.run()
```

How can I make `property` value appear in the console, considering all I can change is `@run` contents?

Corresponding [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tobqarax/)

Comment: oh, shi.. :D please, add an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access to class property:

```
Class::property
```

Answer (score 3):

The code you provided compiles to :

```
var Class;

Class = (function() {
  function Class() {}

  Class.prototype.property = 5;

  Class.run = function() {
    return console.log(this.property);
  };

  return Class;

})();

Class.run();
```

You can see that `property` is attached to the prototype of `Class`, not the class itself. Thus, to access it you can use the `::` in CoffeeScript which is syntastic sugar to access the prototype of a class.

```
Class::property
```

Otherwise, if you really want a static property (which is not the case here), declare it that way:

```
class Class
  @property: 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Class::property`

```
class Class
    property: 5

    @run: ->
        console.log(Class::property)

Class.run()
```

Comment: are you sure your question title modifications are valid? I have no static properties in there.

Comment: @Shtirlits sorry, my bad - I reverted the change.